# FilterAttribute Order not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have 2 attributes that I use within the controllers of my MVC application. AttributeA extends [System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) and AttributeB extends [System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx). I want AttributeB to always be run first.

I have tried all possible combinations of Order based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order.aspx), but AttributeA is **always** run before AttributeB. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction` method with reflector you will see that all filters implementing [IAuthorizationFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx) are invoked before attributes deriving from [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) and that's because authorization is made before invoking the action.

Comment: Thanks! I just hit this on an IAuthorizationFilter registered via Ninject.